Run different CI pipeline files based on branch
I have two different CI files for dev and test envs. I need two separate files because I don't have control over the scripts and because of variable nesting issues with gitlab. This is my current .gitlab-ci.yml:
include:
    - project: marketing/itm/icbf/feature/icbf-mfe-prompt
      ref: Development
      file: .ci/ci.dev.yml
      if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "Development"

    - project: marketing/itm/icbf/feature/icbf-mfe-prompt
      ref: main
      file: .ci/ci.test.yml
      if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"

However, it always runs the latest entry, with is the ci.test.yml file. I tried:
include:
  - project: marketing/itm/icbf/feature/icbf-mfe-prompt
    ref: Development
    file: .ci/ci.dev.yml

  - project: marketing/itm/icbf/feature/icbf-mfe-prompt
    ref: main
    file: .ci/ci.test.yml

stages:
  - build

# Build job that runs everything inside ci.dev.yml
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - .ci/ci.dev.yml
  only:
    - Development  # Run only on the Development branch

Which doesn't work as well. It runs the latest imported file all the same. How to I configure this file so that it runs the ci.dev or ci.test based on the branch instead of always running the latest import?

What is wrong with the 'current' version of the CI YAML? What is the behavior you are seeing? What is the expected behavior? And how are you testing that? I don't think include:if: is a valid key. Are you meaning to use include:rules:if: ?

This is a slightly different approach but you can use that CI file as a dispatcher instead of importing the files directly, so you have a better idea of what ref you should be referring to. Here's an example:
stages: 
  - dispatch

dispatch-pipeline:
  stage: dispatch
  trigger:
    include:
      - project: marketing/itm/icbf/feature/icbf-mfe-prompt #Can be moved to a variable too
        ref: $BRANCH #Switch to $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH if the variable below is removed
        file: $CI_FILE
    strategy: depend
    forward:
      yaml_variables: true
      pipeline_variables: true
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "Development" #Runs whole content of CI for Development
      variables:
        BRANCH: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH #This is a bit redundant and can be removed, but helps understand the example
        CI_FILE: .ci/ci.dev.yml

    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH #Runs whole content of CI for main
      variables:
        BRANCH : $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH #Same applies here
        CI_FILE: .ci/ci.test.yml


The configuration above will create a multi-project pipeline pointing to the specified config in the CI file defined at the variable $CI_FILE

Hey - that seems promising. One detail: stages expects an array, so I had to modify that a bit. However, I am getting this error from gitlab when running your code: jobs:dispatch-pipeline:trigger config contains unknown keys: ref, file
Any thoughts?

Thanks @Pelicer - have edited the answer with the right format, I initally typed the code directly in SO and messed it
